# Inputs in "map" function from R "maps" package

Tags: r, maps

I have a character vector of countries read from a file, like

```
countries <- vector(mode="character")
countries <- c("Germany", "UK", "Canada", "USA", "Colombia", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Portugal")
```

I would like to use this vector as an input in the 'map' function from the 'maps' package; however, this leads to an error:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map(database="world", regions="countries")
Error in map.poly(database, regions, exact, xlim, ylim, boundary, interior, : 
  no recognized region names
```

I have tried using just one item from the vector, so countries[1], but this replicates the same error:

```
map(database="world", regions="countries[1]")
Error in map.poly(database, regions, exact, xlim, ylim, boundary, interior,  : 
  no recognized region names
```

However,

```
ger <- countries[1]
map(database="world", regions="ger")
```

works flawlessly. I can't really wrap my head around this; does map just not take inputs like "countries[1]", or am I overseeing something (perhaps obvious) here? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do `map(database="world", regions=countries)`. When you quote `"countries"`, the call to `map()` looks for a country named `"countries"`, can't find it, and returns an error. The unquoted, variable `countries`, on the other hand, will be evaluated, returning the character vector `c("Germany", "UK", etc...)`, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 map(database="world", regions=map("world", plot=FALSE)$names[
                 unlist( lapply(countries, grep, map("world", plot=FALSE)$names) ) ])
```

There appear to be a few colonial holdings in the Far East that are little specks on the map this produced for me. There were 334 regions plotted. (And only now do I notice that Josh already gave you a more compact solution.)

The problem with `map(database="world", regions="countries[1]")` was that you put quotes around the countries vector. This should have worked: `map(database="world", regions=countries[1])`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I feel a bit stupid... but that really didn't occur to me. Thanks!